# Where does an application store user.config?

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, clickonce

I have on my PC a `C# WinForms` application which was installed via MS *click-once* deployment.

I can see that the `user.config` file used by Settings is located in a folder under:

```
C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\<several other folders>\Data\<version string>
```

but those other folders have seemingly meaningless random names.

How does the app (or the framework, really) know where to find that `user.config` file?
I need to access it from another application, and don't want to have to open a "Find File" dialog for the User to do it...

I have tried searching the Registry for that location, without success.

Thanks

Comment: It's based on several settings within the properties of the project: this has more info on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407899/how-is-user-config-created-and-how-it-is-used

Comment: I had seen that entry, but ty anyway. It doesn't answer the specific question I posed. Maybe only MS know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Application directory

Examine the value of `Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` for the exact directory for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

I found the local user settings stored
C:\Users\ *currentUserName* \AppData\Local\ *my_application*

Where as `Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` returned
C:\Users\ *currentUserName* \AppData\Roaming
But thanks to @raulmd13 for the clue